# Combining Python variables into SQL queries

Tags: python, pandas, database, postgresql, dataframe

I am pulling data from an online database using SQL/postgresql queries and converting it into a Python dataframe using Pandas. I want to be able to change the dates in the SQL query from one point in my Python script instead of having to manually go through every SQL query and change it one by one as there are many queries and many lines in each one.

This is what I have to begin with for example:

```
random_query = """
select *
from table_A as a
where date_trunc('day',a.created_at) >= date('2022-03-01') 
and date_trunc('day',a.created_at) <= date('2022-03-31')

group by 1,2,3

"""
```

Then I will read the data into Pandas as follows:

```
df_random_query = pd.read_sql(random_query, conn)
```

The connection above is to the database - the issue is not there so I am excluding that portion of code here.

What I have attempted is the following:

```
start_date = '2022-03-01'
end_date = '2022-03-31'
```

I have set the above 2 dates as variables and then below I have tried to use them in the SQL query as follows:

```
attempted_solution = """
select *
from table_A as a
where date_trunc('day',a.created_at) >= date( 
""" + start_date + """)
and date_trunc('day',a.created_at) <= date(
""" + end_date + """)

group by 1,2,3
"""
```

This does run but it gives me a dataframe with no data in it - i.e. no numbers. I am not sure what I am doing wrong - any assistance will really help.

Comment: does f string work also ?

Comment: This is called SQL Injection and a classic in hacking.

Comment: read_sql() also takes params as input to avoid SQL injection, see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work it out as follows:

```
start_date = '2022-03-01'
end_date = '2022-03-31'

random_query = f"""
select *
from table_A as a
where date_trunc('day',a.created_at) >= date('start_date') 
and date_trunc('day',a.created_at) <= date('end_date')

group by 1,2,3

"""
```

It was amusing to see that all I needed to do was put start_date and end_date in ' ' as well. I noticed this simply by printing what query was showing in the script. Key thing here is to know how to troubleshoot.

Another option was also to use the `.format()` at the end of the query and inside it say `.format(start_date = '2022-03-01', end_date = '2022-03-31')`.

Answer (score 0):

try dropping `date` function and formatting:

```
my_query = f"... where date_trunc('day', a.created_at) >= {start_date}"
```

Comment: It runs but no data gets pulled - the df is basically empty.

Comment: I dont think you need to pass the 'YYYY/MM/DD' format through `date` function in sql. so you can modify your where clause as 

`"... where date_trunc('day' ,a.created_at) >= {start_date}"`

Comment: I get the following error when I remove the 'date' function: Can not convert parameter '(2022 - 3) - 1' of type [NUMBER(6,0)] into expected type [TIMESTAMP_TZ(9)]